# QTreeView switch tab positions

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreeview

I have a qt object  [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtreeview.html) and I want to switch tab positions. 
Basicly i have a filled TreeView. And the function

```
columnViewportPosition ( int column )
```

returns `0` for the first column and let's say `50` for the second. I want to switch them so that the are displayed in a different order, so that `columnViewportPosition` would return `50` for the first column and `0` for the second. How do i do that?

Comment: Also would accept a way of changing the order of all tabs in a Qtreeview and not just switching of positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out by myself. Its actually really easy.

If we just call the `header()` function to get the [QHeaderView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qheaderview.html), it has all the necessary functions.

For example the function `swapSections` called with `swapSections(1, 0)` will swap the first and second column.